# node_modules/@angular/core/index"' has no exported member 'Version'

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

I am working on ionic/angular 2 and I just took the new clone of my project and ran **npm install**.Now when I run the **ionic serve**, it gives me the following error

```
typescript:/node_modules/@angular/forms/src/version.d.ts, line: 13
        Module '/node_modules/@angular/core/index"' has no exported
        member 'Version'.
```

Here is the **ionic info**

cli packages: (C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules)

```
@ionic/cli-utils  : 1.9.2
ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.9.2
```

global packages:

```
Cordova CLI : 6.5.0
```

local packages:

```
@ionic/app-scripts : 1.3.12
Cordova Platforms  : none
Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 2.0.0-rc.3
```

System:

```
Node : v6.9.1
npm  : 3.10.8
OS   : Windows 10
```

and here is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "myApp",
  "author": "Zohra",
  "homepage": "https://www.example.com/",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "ionic:build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "ionic:serve": "ionic-app-scripts serve"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^4.2.6",
    "@angular/common": "2.1.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.1.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "2.1.1",
    "@angular/core": "2.1.1",
    "@angular/forms": "^2.1.1",
    "@angular/http": "2.1.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.1.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.1.1",
    "@angular/platform-server": "2.1.1",
    "@ionic-native/core": "^3.14.0",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "^3.10.3",
    "@ionic-native/toast": "^3.14.0",
    "@ionic/storage": "1.1.6",
    "angular2-localstorage": "^0.4.0",
    "angular2-moment": "^1.3.0",
    "angularjs-toaster": "^2.1.0",
    "chart.js": "^2.5.0",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "~4.0.3",
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "~1.3.2",
    "gulp-browserify": "^0.5.1",
    "intl": "^1.2.5",
    "ionic-angular": "2.0.0-rc.3",
    "ionic-native": "2.2.3",
    "ionicons": "3.0.0",
    "jquery": "^3.1.1",
    "moment": "^2.17.1",
    "ng2-webstorage": "^1.4.1",
    "rxjs": "^5.0.1",
    "zone.js": "0.6.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@ionic/app-scripts": "^1.2.2",
    "@ionic/cli-plugin-cordova": "^1.0.0-rc.2",
    "@ionic/cli-plugin-gulp": "1.0.2",
    "@ionic/cli-plugin-ionic-angular": "1.3.2",
    "typescript": "2.0.6"
  },
  "cordovaPlugins": [
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist",
    "cordova-plugin-console",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar",
    "cordova-plugin-device",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen",
    "ionic-plugin-keyboard",
    "de.appplant.cordova.plugin.local-notification",
    "cordova-plugin-app-event"
  ],
  "cordovaPlatforms": [
    "android"
  ],
  "description": "Ionic App",
  "config": {
    "ionic_source_map": "source-map"
  },
  "cordova": {
    "plugins": {
      "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": {},
      "cordova-plugin-whitelist": {}
    }
  }
}
```

Please help me

Comment: Looks like a version mismatch in Angular between what your code is written in and what you have installed in `node_modules`. Version export was added somewhere during the version 4. What version do you have installed?

Comment: Hey Lazar! Thanks for your reply. I have updated my question and provided the package.json. Please tell me the suitable changes required to fix the issue.

Comment: If you code is using `version`, it means it was written for Angular version 4. Your `package.json` shows `2.1.1`. Upgrade to the latest version of Angular (4.3.6 at the moment).

Comment: I have updated all of the angular dependencies to 4.6.3and now I am getting the following error
**TypeError: _angular_core.Version is not a constructor**

Comment: did you run `npm install` after updating `package.json`? or change angular/animations to  **2.1.1**

Comment: yes I did run the command